# Laravel: Eloquent `updateOrCreate` with column for creation, but not updated

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

Working in Laravel 9 and am trying to use Eloquent `updateOrCreate`. I am trying to save a company-wide setting and the employees who touch it. `'created_by' => Auth::user()->name` saves the name of the user when the row is created, but it is never meant to be updated. That means it really has no business in the first array (the distinct column(s) that are searched for uniqueness), or the second array (values to be updated each time this update runs).

- If I put `created_by` in the first array, everyone who changes the setting gets their own row.
- If I put `created_by` in the second array, `created_by` gets overwritten with each update, but creation works as expected.
- If I leave it off altogether, when creating I get "*created_by does not have a default value*" error from the database, but updates work as expected.

  ```
   $company_settings = Settings::updateOrCreate(
       [  
          'company_uuid' => Auth::user()->company_uuid, 
          'setting_type' => 1
       ],
       [
          'setting_bool' => $bool_value, 
          'updated_by' => Auth::user()->name, 
          'created_by' => Auth::user()->name
       ],
   );
  ```

**How do I save the name of the user who creates the record, but never update it?**

Is there any syntax that would allow me to feed columns that do not have default values, but do not need to be updated? Do I just need to abandon `updateOrCreate` and execute my own create / update code?

Comment: Have you considered listening to the Eloquent `created` event to save the user id when the model is first created? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events

Answer (score 0):

In the model:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::creating(function($model) {
        $model->created_by = now();
    });
}
```